# Move a non-convex polygon's outline inwards?

Tags: c#, geometry, curves, computational-geometry, outline

[image: The given code produces undesirable loops.]

The polygons are small 3D parts of a quasi sphere centered in the origin and a solution that works in the plane can easily be made to work in this world.

I tried to move the outline inwards by using the same algorithm that draws the black lines in the example given on the picture, with different values.

```
private Vector3[] MoveOutlineInwards(Vector3[] outline, float byLength)
{
    Vector3[] result = new Vector3[outline.Length];

    result[0] = outline[0] - Vector3.Cross(outline[1] - outline[0], outline[0]).normalized * byLength;
    result[^1] = outline[^1] - Vector3.Cross(outline[^1] - outline[^2], outline[^1]).normalized * byLength;

    for (int i = 1; i < outline.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        // outline[i] is quasi perpendicular to the triangle formed by the three
        // vertices outline[i - 1], outline[i], outline[i + 1], because these are close and part of a sphere centered in the origin.
        // As such, it is used for an efficiency purpose as the second parameter when computing each cross product.

        Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross((outline[i] - outline[i - 1]).normalized + (outline[i + 1] - outline[i]).normalized, outline[i]).normalized;
        cross *= 1f / Mathf.Sin(0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad * Vector3.Angle(outline[i - 1] - outline[i], outline[i + 1] - outline[i]));

        result[i] = outline[i] - cross * byLength;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The problem is that it produces curve 'crossings' and 'loopings' (Sorry, not a native English speaker.) which I have been failing to detect with different algorithms (sum of angles, for instance).

Does someone have a means to efficiently detect them, or a completely different but better approach at moving the outline inwards?